# c programing function paycheck

Tags: c

I am struggling to learn how to program in C
Right now I am stuck trying to code a paycheck program

It`s gonna be easy for you guys. I am a very beginner

I don`t know how to call my function

Can you guys help me?

Thank you a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float calculatePay(float payRate, float hours);
float hours = 50;
float payRate = 10;
float regHours;
float overtimeHours;
float regPay;
float overtimePay;
float grossPay;
float overtimeRate1 = 0.5;

int main()
{
    printf("The pay check for the first person is: %0.2f\n", calculatePay(payRate, hours), grossPay+overtimePay);
}
float calculatePay(float payRate, float hours)
{
    regPay = regHours * payRate;
    overtimePay = overtimeHours * payRate * overtimeRate1;
    grossPay = regPay + overtimePay;

    if (hours <= 40){
        regHours = hours;
        overtimeHours = 0;
        return grossPay+overtimePay;
    }
    else if (hours > 40);{
        regHours = 40;
        overtimeHours = regHours - 40;
        return grossPay+overtimePay;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove that `grossPay+overtimePay` inside the `printf()` statement.

Comment: `else (hours > 40);{` --> `else {`

Comment: Read quickly [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Be sure to ask for all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float calculatePay(); // Changed function prototype
// Global floats are default initialized to 0
float hours = 50;
float payRate = 10;
float regHours;
float overtimeHours;
float regPay;
float overtimePay;
float grossPay;
float overtimeRate1 = 0.5;
int main() {
  printf("Enter gross pay, over time pay and overtime hours:\n");
  if (scanf("%f %f %f", &grossPay, &overtimePay, &overtimeHours)<3) {
    perror("input failure for gross pay, over time pay and overtime");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("The pay check for the first person is: %0.2f\n",
         calculatePay()); // No need to pass arguments, since they are global
                          // variables
}
float calculatePay() {
  regPay = regHours * payRate;
  overtimePay = overtimeHours * payRate * overtimeRate1;
  grossPay = regPay + overtimePay;
  if (hours <= 40) {
    regHours = hours;
    overtimeHours = 0;
    return grossPay + overtimePay;
  }
  // else { No need of else condition since you are returning in if
  regHours = 40;
  overtimeHours = regHours - 40;
  return grossPay + overtimePay;
  //}
}
```

Explanation(for novice; please read linked documentation):

- The variables you have used are declared outside the any function and thus are [global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).
- You can use declare the variables inside the function ([local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable)) and pass them to `calculatePay` function as argument.
- `main` is the [default function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) which gets executed when you run a C program.
- You can read the values from the input using the [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function; don't forget to test its return count.
- You can print messages to the screen using the [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function; since `stdout` is buffered (often line buffered) you usually want to end its format control string with `\n` (or call [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) appropriately).
- `%d`, `%f`, etc are called format specifiers which are used inside the string of `printf` or `scanf` which denote the datatype of the variable like int, float,etc respectively.
- You have to write the prototype of the function (like `void foo(int, int);`), if functions are defined after `main` function which, also called function declaration.
- You can call a function like function_name(argument1, argument2, ...) according to the respective [function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (and improve your code to get no warnings). If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-prototypes -g`.

Comment: You miss a few English sentences of explanation

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  Could you please elaborate on what I am missing

Comment: Just add a few sentences in English, for a newbie, explaining your code. BTW, I recommend checking the return count of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Okay will do it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch take a look

Comment: Good, I upvoted your revised answer!

Comment: I also took time to edit your answer and add links to (useful) external documentation. For your next answers, consider providing such links.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sure, I will provide links for next answers. Good work dude. Thank you